# VirtualBox Increase Size of Ubuntu Linux- not reflected

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed as a VM on my VirtualBOx.
In the beginning I had 10GB and then I increased it to 30GB following the steps here: http://www.redstk.com/resizing-a-virtualbox-5-1-4-hdd-vdi-file/
I had 2partions: 1. Linux 2.Extended(with Swap). While I formatted the Extended partition to include the new size I had deleted the Swap partition altogether.
After rebooting, I see that the Extended partition shows me the new size however this somehow doesn't seem to be "recognized" by the system and I always see my disk running out of space and the total dis space only shows the 10 GB like this:
[disk usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoFnN.jpg)

I have not done the logical mapping steps that are included in the post because I didn't find any /dev/mapper filesystems:( Could this be a reason?
Here is how the partitions look like on gParted:[gParted partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE9Um.jpg)

Here is how my ubuntu command looks like:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
sda      8:0    0   30G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda1   8:1    0    8G  0 part /
```

Output of command [fdisk -l /dev/sda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Spm.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Have you done resize2fs or so?
Run `lsblk` in VM and `df -h` ; If you see they both differ, it means OS has knowledge of extended disk space but filesystem doesn't.

Comment: Yes they differ. But how can the filesystem be made to know of the changes?

Comment: @acsrujan Please see the updated post

Comment: Please show `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

Comment: Please see updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the output of `fdisk -l`, you now have:

- `/dev/sda1` is an 8 GB primary partition, mounted on `/`
- `/dev/sda2` is an empty 22 GB extended partition.

If your goal is to allocate the 22 GB to `/dev/sda1` you can delete the useless extended partition and then extend `/dev/sda1`. You can either use a graphical tool such as `gparted` (`sudo apt-get install gparted` if necessary) or use command-line tools:

- Delete the useless extended partition:

  `sudo parted /dev/sda rm 2`
- Extend the first primary partition to the end of the disk:

  `sudo parted /dev/sda -- resizepart 1 -1s`
- Extend the filesystem to cover the newly acquired space; assuming that `/` is the default ext4:

  `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`